# Correct way to take a function from the current shell and save it for future use?

Tags: bash, function

I've been writing a lot of one-off functions recently. On the occasions that I go "hmm, I should save this" I use `type <function name>` to show the code, and copy and paste it into .bashrc. Is there a faster way to do this, or some standard or command built for this purpose?

FWIW, I'm just doing this on my personal computer running Mint, so conveniences like copy and paste are easy. However, I'm also interested in answers specific to shell-only environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Korn-like shells, including `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash` and `yash`, you can do:

```
typeset -fp myfunc
```

To print the definition of the `myfunc` function.

So you can add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` with:

```
typeset -fp myfunc >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: So there is a suitable command! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> some standard or command built for this purpose

I don't know, but you can use type + tail + redirection

For example, I have a function `edit()`. Here is my `type edit` output:

```
edit — это функция
edit () 
{ 
    for arg in "$@";
    do
        if which "$arg" > /dev/null; then
            subl $(realpath $(which "$arg"));
        else
            echo "$arg not found";
        fi;
    done
}
```

To supress first line `edit — это функция` I use `tail -n +2`:

```
$ type edit | tail -n +2
edit () 
{ 
    for arg in "$@";
    do
        if which "$arg" > /dev/null; then
            subl $(realpath $(which "$arg"));
        else
            echo "$arg not found";
        fi;
    done
}
```

Then I need to redirect this output to .bash_profile or .bashrc or whatever else:
`type edit | tail -n +2 >> $HOME/.bash_profile`

Now let's check if `edit` is really a function:
`type -t edit` will output only one word `function` if its argument is a function.

Final solution looks like:

```
add_to_bash_profile() {
    local type_of_arg="$(type -t $1)"
    if [ "$type_of_arg" == "function" ]
    then 
        echo >> $HOME/.bash_profile #adding empty line for readability of .bash_profile
        type $1 | tail -n +2 >> $HOME/.bash_profile
    else
        echo "$1 is not a function"
    fi
}
```

and now you can add this function to your .bash_profile:

```
add_to_bash_profile add_to_bash_profile
```

Comment: You can also check that `.bash_profile` contains such function by grepping it.

Comment: Very nice answer! I would put `type function | tail -n+2 >> ~/.bashrc` in a TL;DR (note that OP uses `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`).

Comment: I really appreciate the answer and the time you took walking through each step! +1 for teaching me "it's a function" in Russian.